# Barrier in ios like android ConstraintLayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

I want to place a button below two multiline labels like below.

[image]

**This can be done in android using ConstraintLayout barrier want to know how this can be done in ios Storyboard**

Comment: Have you tried putting the multiline labels inside a UIStackView? Or just a plain view? Then attach the button.top to the view.bottom.

Comment: Simple layout i am using

Answer (score 1):

`StackView` allow you to create them.
[image]

***- Storyboard constraint***

[image]

[image]

- `StackView` are available at the bottom of the storyboard. 
  You can refer to the picture below.

[image]

- In detail, you can set each property in the `StackView` and `Label`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `UIStackView` for the two labels and attach the `UIButton` to the bottom of the `UIStackView`.
The following screenshot should clarify this:

[image: Interfacebuilder]

The `UIStackView` is set to `axis` = `horizontal` and `Alignment` = `Top`.

[image: UIStackView settings]

You may want to add some spacing.

These are the constraints I've used:

[image: Constraints]

Comment: How to do it with stack view?

Comment: As shown in the screenshot. Place the stack view at the top, the two labels inside the stack view and the button below. Then add the constraints as shown in the third screenshot.